# Open added files in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, file-io

First I added files to my xcode project using "Add Files to "Project"...", then I tried to open that files using fopen(file_name, "r"), but I get the error file not found.
After that, googling, I edit the Scheme, check custom working directory, and I set it to Users/.../myProjectFolder

And all works fine now, but how can I open imported files without using the custom working directory?

Comment: The files are on-disk *somewhere*. You either have to open them without full or relative path specification (i.e. they must be in the current working directory) or provide a qualified path to their location. (fully qualified or relative to the current working directory). One way or another, just because files are in the Xcode project file list doesn't magically make them available to a unqualified `fopen()` call. they have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the directory where the compiled code is run and the source code directory are two different directories.

The best way to get your compiled code to open the file from within the source directory is to make it parse the command line and in the Xcode *run settings* pass `$(SOURCE_DIR)/myfile.txt` as an argument.

You might use the following code to parse the command line:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: myprog filename\n");
        return 1;
    }
    const char *filename = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    ...

}
```